# CSS keyframes only works in Chrome

Tags: css, css-animations

i'm trying to make a simple animation using keyframes, but it only works in Chrome. Here is the code (i've only included keyframes code once, for shorter post):

```
@keyframes logokf {
    0% {
    background-image: url('gfx/logo1.png');
    }    
    20% {
    background-image: url('gfx/logo2.png');
    }    
    40% {
    background-image: url('gfx/logo3.png');
    }    
    60% {
    background-image: url('gfx/logo4.png');
    }    
    80% {
    background-image: url('gfx/logo1.png');
    }    
    100% {
    background-image: url('gfx/logo1.png');
    }

}


@-webkit-keyframes logokf {    
}

@-moz-keyframes logokf {             
}

@-o-keyframes logokf { 
}

@-ms-keyframes logokf {
}

#logo:hover {
float: left;
height: 75px;
margin: 28px 0 22px;
width: 276px;

/*animation-name*/
-webkit-animation-name:logokf;
-moz-animation-name:logokf;
-ms-animation-name:logokf;
-o-animation-name:logokf;
animation-name:logokf;

/*animation-duration*/
-webkit-animation-duration:1s;
-moz-animation-duration:1s;
-ms-animation-duration:1s;
-o-animation-duration:1s;
animation-duration:1s;

/*animation-iteration-count*/
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;

/*animation-timing-function*/
-webkit-animation-timing-function:lineare;
-moz-animation-timing-function:lineare;
-ms-animation-timing-function:lineare;
-o-animation-timing-function:lineare;
animation-timing-function:lineare;

/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:0s;
-moz-animation-delay:0s;
-ms-animation-delay:0s;
-o-animation-delay:0s;
animation-delay:0s;

 }
```

Any thoughts of how can i fix it or keyframes are not yet supported from other browsers?

Comment: You've spelt 'linear' as lineare, I don't know if this would cause some broweser to drop the whole animation or if its just a typo.

Comment: @Dpolehonski oops yes it was a typo. but it worked in Chrome i guess cause linear is the default value. anyway still doesn't work in any other browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background-image itself does not appear to be [a valid transitionable property.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/) It may happen to work in Chrome, but it's probably just lucky. When it's implemented, you'll be looking to use the [crossfade capability](http://peter.sh/files/examples/cross-fading.html) in CSS images.

Comment: thank you, i got confused and i didn't thought of that because because as you said, luckily worked in Chrome. For future reference, the right way to implement what i'm trying, is to use opacity for animation with absolute positioning of background images.

Comment: Or to create a sprite image and change background-position.