# -moz-transition not working in my css

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSS keyframes only works in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622598/css-keyframes-only-works-in-chrome)

My site uses css transitions to fade in new images on the three icons (facebook, twitter, email). The transitions work well on Chrome, but not in Firefox. Here's the css snipper:

```
.link-button > div{height:79px; width:79px; display:inline-block; zoom: 1; *display:inline; 
transition: 0.5s;
-moz-transition: 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s;
-o-transition: 0.5s;}

.link-button .facebook{background:url(../img/bt_facebook.png) center center no-repeat transparent;}
.link-button .facebook:hover{background-image:url(../img/bt_facebook_over.png);}
.link-button .twitter{background:url(../img/bt_twitter.png) center center no-repeat transparent;}
.link-button .twitter:hover{background-image:url(../img/bt_twitter_over.png);}
.link-button .email{background:url(../img/bt_email.png) center center no-repeat transparent;}
.link-button .email:hover{background-image:url(../img/bt_email_over.png);}
```

I'm assuming that my error is directly with the -moz-transition because the :hover state works, but not the transition. I've copied the transition code from w3 school, so I know it's not incorrect, but my Firefox correctly fires the css transitions found on the internet, so I know it's not my browser being faulty. It must be something fundamental I've overlooked.

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry what I wrote in my answer was incorrect (misunderstood your question!) so I've deleted it. obviously `background` was correct and stands for the equivalent of `transition-property` in the shorthand :)

Comment: Ok thanks Luca! I quickly updated my question because the 'background' code wasn't supposed to be there, so sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSS3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-image) says `background-image` cannot be animated. The `background-image` transition in Chrome is nonstandard.